How can I search for data if a template is specified in the database?
There’s a WP site with thousands of custom posts, each with an ACF field called VIN, storing car VINs like W1K253???1??????? or W1N253???1???????.
The ? marks represent any alphanumeric value, limited by their number. Their position varies between models, so there’s no single search pattern.
We need to implement a search where users enter their full VIN, e.g., W1K25312311234567, and it feeds posts with matching patterns like W1K253???1???????.
Have you tried this:

    $vin_regex = str_replace(array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'), '.', $vin_regex);

    
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'vin',
            'value' => $vin_regex,
            'compare' => 'REGEXP', 
        ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);


It didn't help
ave you tried this
    $query = "
        SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
          AND p.post_status = 'publish'
          AND pm.meta_key = 'vin'
          AND pm.meta_value LIKE REPLACE(%s, '?', '_')
        LIMIT 10 OFFSET %d
    ";

    $results = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($query, $vin_input, $offset));

It didn't help

Please give much clearer examples of the data stored in the database, the values the user might enter, and the results you want to get from your query for those values. Your current description is very unclear, unfortunately. Thanks

There’s a WP site with thousands of custom posts, each with an ACF field called VIN, storing car VINs like W1K253???1??????? or W1N253???1???????.
The ? marks represent any alphanumeric value, limited by their number. Their position varies between models, so there’s no single search pattern.
We need to implement a search where users enter their full VIN, e.g., W1K25312311234567, and it feeds posts with matching patterns like W1K253???1???????.

It's still unclear. One example isn't enough. And it's unclear what feeds posts with matching patterns like W1K253???1???????1 actually means in practice. If the user enters a specific VIN, surely it should just return any record with that exact VIN? Or are you saying it should return any VINS starting with W1K253 and with a 1 in those other places, but anything in between? It's very ambiguous. Again, please edit your question to give multiple examples of the stored source data, some examples of expected user input,  and the exact results you'd expect from those inputs and source data.

And a complete explanation of the number format would probably help, too - please don't assume we know anything about that specific format. It may be unique to a single country or territory, and even then, programmers from that area still may not have worked with it. See also [ask] if you need more general guidance on asking a good question here. Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question is also relevant. We'd like to help but we need better info. Thanks.
